# Why someone would use Java command line option -Xrs today?

Tags: java, jvm, signals

Why someone would use Java command line option -Xrs ?

According to the Java documentation, the option avoids the JVM to handle signals.

In which case you'd want to do that?

Comment: To prevent the JVM to handle signals ? To be honest, I don't know but I prefer to use a system that provide to many option instead of one that you need to find workaround for every specific needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> If the Java VM is run as a service (for example, the servlet engine
>   for a web server), then it can receive CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT but should
>   not initiate shutdown because the operating system will not actually
>   terminate the process. To avoid possible interference such as this,
>   the -Xrs command-line option was added beginning with J2SE 1.3.1.

Comment: So this seems to be related only to MS Windows. Is there a valid use case for Linux as execution environment?

Comment: @OGrandeDiEnne SORRY. I'm not able to answer it since I know little about unix